# AspCore 2.x - custom LoggerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After update core to 2.x, I encountered the problem with my Logger.
I need to log some information about requests (URL, headers, etc). 
In asp core 1.x I created my provider and registered it in

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddAppLogger((n, l) => l >= LogLevel.Error || n.EndsWith("AppLogger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), app.ApplicationServices);
    }
```

I used app.ApplicationServices (IServiceProvider) in order to get in AppLogger instance of

```
var httpContext = _serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext;
```

But something broke after the update, I see that in old scheme does not create the instance of my logger. I read that in new version we need to register LoggerProvider like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddProvider(new AppLoggerProvider((n, l) => l >= LogLevel.Error || n.EndsWith("AppLogger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    webHost.Run();
}
```

Or need to use method service.AddLogging in StartUp.cs
But in this case, I can't get IHttpContextAccessor or IServiceProvider.
I saw the code of other popular loggers, but they don't use IHttpContextAccessor.
Maybe somebody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. 
First, we add AppLoggerProvider

```
public static class AppLoggerExtensions
{

    public static ILoggingBuilder AddAppLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, AppLoggerProvider>();
        return builder;
    }
}
```

I rewrited constructor of my logger, and now use IHttpContextAccessor :

```
    public AppLogger(string name, Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = null)
    {
        this._name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "AppLogger" : name;
        this._filter = filter;
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
```

Then we register func in services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add Logging logics
            services.AddSingleton(provider =>
                new Func<string, LogLevel, bool>((n, l) => l >= LogLevel.Error || n.EndsWith("AppLogger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
        }
```

And register logger in Programm.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(config => config.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("config\\appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"config\\appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    // Add custom logger
                    logging.AddAppLogger();

                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        logging.AddDebug();
                    }

                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()

                .Build();


            host.Run();
        }
```